# How to programmatically retrieve errors from an azure synapse pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics, azure-synapse-pipeline

How can I programmatically retrieve error messages from each run of an azure synapse pipeline ?   Obviously if this was a normal binary I could redirect stderr and/or stdout by executing the binary from a shell wrapper, however its not that simple here since this is auto launched daily based on a cloud based azure synapse pipeline trigger.

I have many pipelines and wish to achieve this without having to modify the underlying pipelines themselves ( but will if I must )

Any suggestions ?    Yes synapse pipelines are a no-code solution however I need access to errors to drive my downstream processing

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure SDK, under the Artifacts namespace, you can use the [PipelineRunClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.analytics.synapse.artifacts.pipelinerunclient?view=azure-dotnet-preview) class to get information about the run.

Here is some code I use to capture the Status of a run, but it could be used for other properties as well.

```
protected async Task<PipelineRun> GetRunAsync(string runId)
{
    var run = await Client.GetPipelineRunAsync(runId);
    return run.Value;
}

public async Task<string> GetStatusAsync(string runId)
{
    var run = await GetRunAsync(runId);
    return run.Status;
}
```

The *Client* object in this case is a PipelineRunClient. *run.Value* is a [PipelineRun](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.analytics.synapse.artifacts.models.pipelinerun?view=azure-dotnet-preview) object, which includes the following [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.analytics.synapse.artifacts.models.pipelinerun?view=azure-dotnet-preview#properties):
[image]

I have not tested it, but I assume if the *Status* is Failed, the *Message* property would contain the error message text.